# Very basic android code posts error. java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I made the program as simple as possible. But still the `logcat` says that an error occurred while execution doInBackground().

Here is my code

```
package com.example.basicasynctask;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new myFunc().execute();
}

private class myFunc extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "preExecute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inBackground", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "postExecute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
}
```

Comment: Probably due to calling `Toast.makeText` from `doInBackground `

Comment: Dont change UI elements from "doInBackground()". Logging doesn't hurt, Toasts do.

Comment: Probably because ```makeText``` might be on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a `Toast` in `doInBackground` you can but you have to run it on a UI thread with `runOnUIThread()`.

If you can wait the end of the `doInBackground` process you will be able to show the `Toast` message in the `onPostExecute` method without running it on a UI thread

Comment: Hey that actually was the problem. I set a flag to manage the contents of the Toast which i then showed in onPostExecute. Thanks!

Comment: @JayGhosh, no problem, hope it helped you.

Comment: Hi @Jay Ghosh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @Onik I'm sorry I am new to this and didn't know that.